# How to get the numbers of CheckBox checked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am writing this code, but unable to get anything. Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
     <head>
       <script>
         function computeMarks() {
           var inputElems = document.form1.getElementsByTagName("input");
           var count = 0;
           for (var i =0; i<=inputElems.length; i++) {
             if(inputElems[i].type === "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked) {
               count++;
             }
           }
           alert(count);
         }
       </script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <form name="form1" id="form1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="quiz" value=1 /> Hi
         <input type="checkbox" name="quiz" value=1 /> Bye
         <input type="checkbox" name="quiz" value=1 /> See ya
         <input type="button" onClick="computeMarks()" value="Compute Marks"/>
       </form>
     </body>
   </html>
```

I have tried to do getElementByName("quiz") but the same thing is happening.

Comment: change your for loop condition to < inputElems.length and everything should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `i<=inputElems.length` to `i < inputElems.length`. Array indexes run from `0` to `length-1`. You're getting an error when `i` is `inputElements.length` (when your scripts don't work, isn't the Javascript console the first place you look for help?).

DEMO[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/w80q7ghr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Well what you need to do is just remove **=** sign from **<=** in your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
     <head>
       <script>
         function computeMarks() {
           var inputElems = document.form1.getElementsByTagName("input");
           var count = 0;
           for (var i =0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {
             if(inputElems[i].type === "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked) {
               count++;
             }
           }
           alert(count);
         }
       </script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <form name="form1" id="form1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="quiz" value=1 /> Hi
         <input type="checkbox" name="quiz" value=1 /> Bye
         <input type="checkbox" name="quiz" value=1 /> See ya
         <input type="button" onClick="computeMarks()" value="Compute Marks"/>
       </form>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommand the JQuery to do this, it's way easier. Here is an example if you use JQuery in your code instead of plain javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
     <head>
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
       <script>
         function computeMarks() {

           var counter = 0;
           $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                if($(this).prop('checked'))
                {
                    counter++;
                }
           });

           alert(counter);
         }
       </script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <form name="form1" id="form1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="quiz" value=1 /> Hi
         <input type="checkbox" name="quiz" value=1 /> Bye
         <input type="checkbox" name="quiz" value=1 /> See ya
         <input type="button" onClick="computeMarks()" value="Compute Marks"/>
       </form>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I don't think jQuery is mentioned anywhere in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the reference of the form and loop through it's elements to see if they are checked or not, simply replace your function with this and it should work:

```
function computeMarks() {
    var checked = 0;
    var form = document.getElementById("form1");
           var index, element;
    for (index = 0; index < form.elements.length; ++index) {
        element = form.elements[index];
        // You may want to check `element.name` here as well
        if (element.type.toUpperCase() == "CHECKBOX" && element.checked) 
            ++checked;

    }
    alert(checked);
}
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/cpgmdfs6/)**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you query the elements, and add the event in JavaScript, for example:

```
var form = document.form1
var button = form.querySelector('[type="button"]')
var checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]')

var computeMarks = function(els) {
  return []
    .map.call(els, function(x){return +x.checked})
    .reduce(function(x, y){return x + y})
}

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(computeMarks(checkboxes))
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u59c3d1L/2/